# How to determine and use the actual java path in a Linux shell script

Tags: java, linux, shell

In a bash shell script on Ubuntu/Mint, I need to create some symlinks in the /jre/lib/ext/ directory under the java installation directory.

For example, if openjdk6 is the default java, /usr/bin/java points to:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
```

I can find this in my script with:

```
MYJAVAPATH=readlink -f `which java`
```

The path I would need in my shell script would be based on part of that path, plus the path fragment above:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/
```

Can anyone tell me to to derive the path immediately above in a bash shell script? Thanks.

Comment: Could you just cd to that directory, back up to /jre/, then go into lib/ext ?  Once there, then ln -s and get your symlinks in place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply append the relative part `../lib/ext/`

```
MYJAVAPATH="$(readlink -f $(which java))"
LIB_EXT="$(dirname ${MYJAVAPATH})/../lib/ext"
```

and then use `${LIB_EXT}`.

Comment: That is a complete answer. Thanks. And other than doing this: cd $LIB_EXT; LIB_EXT=$(pwd), how can I get rid of the /../ path element?

Comment: also, I don't want to have to install any additional programs (such as realpath).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dirname` such as

```
javalink=`which java`
javapath=`readlink $javalink`
javadir=`dirname $javapath`
```